# Get the Maximum and current value of Scrollbar in Listview

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

As the title say:

I want to know values of a scrollbar in the ListView such as:

1. Minimum value I know = 0 :)
2. Maximum value of a scrollbar
3. Current value (position of a bar inside of a scrollbar)

Is this possible?

How to make it work for both iOS and Android?

I have tried with ItemAppear to get the position in the ListView but all I can get is the position of an item not the actual scrollbar position and with ItemAppear the problem is if I have big images in the list then I scroll 1 mile but nothing happens until the other item appears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ListView doesn't fire Scrolled events like ScrollView does.

If you still want to get current value or maximum value of scrollbar, I suggest you can render new Listview, that contains scrolled event. or you can search some third party control, may be have this event.

Comment: Do you know how would I render new listview with scroll event? How to do this?